# Make the opacity in module the background not text or images

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jhtml

How do I go about making the text in a module not affected by the opacity for the white background.

For example on this page.

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/services

In this page I would like the text and 3 images to not be affected by the opacity only the white background.

Answer (score 3):

In your template.css replace:

```
.servpricing {
background: #FFF;
color: #000;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
```

with:

```
.servpricing {
background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
background: rgba(255,255,255,.3); // transparent white
color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this css for transparent backgrounds only

> background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);

Answer (score 1):

To have a white background only with an opacity, use the following:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
background: url(../images/transparent_white.png) repeat;
```

`255, 255, 255` are the `rgb` values for white and `0.3` is the level of transparency. I've also included a fallback image for older browsers that do not support `rgba`. If you want to keep it, you will of course have to create the transparent **png** and possibly the path of it.

Hope this helps